# Put string in another cell in excel

Tags: android, excel

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener { 

    TextView text_fname, text_lname;
    EditText edit_fname, edit_lname;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        text_fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text_lname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        edit_fname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edit_lname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit2);

        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String fname1 = text_fname.getText().toString();
        String fname2 = edit_fname.getText().toString();

        String lname1 = text_lname.getText().toString();
        String lname2 = edit_lname.getText().toString();    

        String space = " ";
        String newLine = "\n";

        File file = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            file = getActivity().getFilesDir();
            fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("test.xls", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(fname1.getBytes());
            fos.write(space.getBytes());
            fos.write(fname2.getBytes());
            fos.write(newLine.getBytes());
            fos.write(lname1.getBytes());
            fos.write(space.getBytes());
            fos.write(lname2.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (fos!=null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File saved in " + file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

How can I put the fname2 and lname2 in the next cell when I open it in excel? I tried adding " " but it only add space. Here's the current output:

[image]

What I want is, the "mickey" and the "mouse" to be on the column B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that when you add a space it is literally just adding the character to your input, rather than telling Excel that you are looking at a new tab when you open it.

Try using `\s` instead of a space.

It might also be possible that a tab, rather than a space, is interepreted as a new cell, so I would give `\t` a go as well.

Also worth looking at the `.csv` file format, rather than `.xls` as `.csv` uses comma separated values instead and may be easier to read/write as your application gets more complicated, as it can be read into a String and processed easier in Java.

Answer (score 0):

excel see new column when `;` appears you should try `space=";"`